# Jenkins compiler warnings plugin not showing C or C++ source code

Tags: jenkins

My build script includes

> make clean
>   make all

make invokes gcc:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

my post-build step is to, "scan for compiler warnings" and I chose the parser for `GNU C Compiler 4 (gcc)`.

Is that enough? Did I miss anything?

My console log shows

```
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in console log with parser GNU C Compiler 4 (gcc)
[WARNINGS] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #72
```

When I click on the compiler warnings chart and drill down to a single source file, I get

```
Copying the source file '../software_under_test/maths.c' from the workspace to the build folder '8410a4f3.tmp' on the Jenkins master failed.
02 Seems that the path is relative, however an absolute path is required when copying the sources.
03 Is the file 'maths.c' contained more than once in your workspace?
04 Is the file '../software_under_test/maths.c' a valid filename?
05 If you are building on a slave: please check if the file is accessible under '$JENKINS_HOME/[job-name]/../software_under_test/maths.c'
06 If you are building on the master: please check if the file is accessible under '$JENKINS_HOME/[job-name]/workspace/../software_under_test/maths.c'
07 java.io.IOException: Failed to copy ../software_under_test/maths.c to /home/mawg/.jenkins/jobs/plain_C_project/builds/73/workspace-files/8410a4f3.tmp
08   at hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:1991)
09   at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.Files.copyFilesWithAnnotationsToBuildFolder(Files.java:80)
10   at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.copyFilesWithAnnotationsToBuildFolder(HealthAwareRecorder.java:312)
11   at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:89)
12   at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.perform(HealthAwareRecorder.java:259)
13   at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:75)
14   at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
16   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
17   at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
18   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
19   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
20   at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
21   at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
22   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
23 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../software_under_test/maths.c (No such file or directory)
24   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
25   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
26   at hudson.FilePath$41.invoke(FilePath.java:2017)
27   at hudson.FilePath$41.invoke(FilePath.java:2012)
28   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
29   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
30   at hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:2012)
31   at hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:1986)
32   ... 14 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

[This page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20150) says that the code is looking for the string "Entering directory" in the build output and [the code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/warnings/parser/GnuMakeGccParser.java) verifies this.

I tweaked my make step to output that by adding the `--print-directory` to the make command and got

```
+ make all --print-directory
make: Entering directory `/home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/Debug'
Building file: ../test_scripts/test_maths.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -DUNIT_TEST -I"/home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/mocks" -I"/home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/software_under_test" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"test_scripts/test_maths.d" -MT"test_scripts/test_maths.d" -o "test_scripts/test_maths.o" "../test_scripts/test_maths.c"
Finished building: ../test_scripts/test_maths.c
```

etc, but that did not help.

So, can anyone tell me how to configure things so that I an drill down into the source code from the Jenkins compiler warnings plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved!

The problem was that the makefile generated by Eclipse contain ed a relative path. Relative to the makefile directory that it, but the Jenkins compiler warning plugin was treating it as relative to the Jenkins workspace.

The solution is to edit the makeilfe. Do it once for a manually created makefile. If you use Eclipse it constantly regenerates the makefiles, so the trick is to edit the Jenkins shell script to change the makefile on the fly, immediately prior to building.

Note that I only changed the makefile for the Software Under Test directory. I am not interested in compiler warnings in Google Test, etc

So, now my Jenkins shell script starts

```
cd /home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/Debug

# Tweak the makefile to use an absolute path to the Software Under Test.
# If we use a relative path then the Jenkins comiler wanrings plugin
# cannot find the source code to display it, so that we can drill down
# into it and see the compiler warnings in situ.
sed 's|\.\./software_under_test/maths.c|/home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/software_under_test/maths.c|g' /home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/Debug/software_under_test/subdir.mk > /home/mawg/workspace/unit_test_C_code_example_project/Debug/software_under_test/subdir.mk.absolute
rm software_under_test/subdir.mk
mv software_under_test/subdir.mk.absolute software_under_test/subdir.mk

make clean
# The --print-directory option is required for the compiler warning plugin
make all --print-directory
```

Answer (score 3):

This was one of the first results when I had this problem, but I have since found that as of at least 2018-07 there is an advanced setting to “Resolve relative paths” (not sure when this was added), but this solved the same problem for me

**Update:**
After adding the *Scan for compiler warnings* Post Build action in Jenkins, there will be an Advanced button.

[image: Jenkins Warning plugin "Post Build" action main view]

After clicking *Advanced* a list of options appears. Some way down this list there is a section titled *Resolve relative paths*, clicking on this solved my problem.

[image: *Resolve relative paths* option in the Advanced setting section]

This was in the *Warning* plugin version 4.66

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or other information about where to find “Resolve relative paths”.

Comment: Please do, and I will upvote. In fact, I will change the answer to this, to keep up with the times :-)

Comment: Hopefully the information added provides the details on resolving relative paths!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I had the same Problem and got rid of it after following changes:

1. I set the at the Source Code Management-->Local module Directory
   a Period following the checkout Folder of the Project i.e. "./project1"
   I didnt have the "./" before.
2. I added also to the make command the Option --print-directory.

Now it works as expected!